# Seeing ads overlap the question's content

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

For the last month or so, I've been seeing the ads permanently pop over the content. I'm running the latest Chrome on Mac OS Mountain Lion. It seems to happen on about 50% of the answers I open. Is this by design?

[image: Overlapping ads example image]

Comment: When you say latest Chrome, you mean latest _stable_?

Comment: Yes, the latest stable.

Comment: Birth announcements?  Programmers don't give birth.  Surely you picked up some malware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We only show one banner ad at the top of the question:

[image]

And we keep them relevant to software development in one way or another. I'm going to venture a guess that the Tinyprints banner you see is not ours.

Comment: It looks like I had a bad Chrome extension: "Neat Bookmarks" (http://stopmalvertising.com/malvertisements/beware-of-the-google-chrome-extension-neat-bookmarks.html). Thanks for the help.